# Unable to view alert in the browser window

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have written a code to display an error message if the user login fails. The servlet code is as follows:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);


/*User class is a Java bean with an isValid attribute*/
  User user= new User(); 
  if (!user.isValid()) {
         request.setAttribute("errorMessage"," Invalid Parameters!");
         request.getRequestDispatcher("RegistrationPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
  }



// RegistrationPage.jsp file code snippet is below


<script>
function loginFailure() {
           System.out.println("Invalid parameters");
           if(request.getParameter("errorMessage") != null) {
              alert("<%= request.getParameter("errorMessage") %>");        
           }

</script>

<body onload="loginFailure()">
</body>
```

I cannot understand why the page is not displaying the alert message when there is a failure in the login. It does go into the method for loginFailure and to the alert function as well.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `getAttribute("errorMessage")` in your scriplet?

Answer (score 1):

First, as @PM 77-1 says, you need to do `getAttribute()` not `getParameter()`.  Also, don't you want that `System.out` to execute only if the conditional is true?  But the larger problem is that you're mixing up your Java and JavaScript.  Your conditional `if(request.getParameter("errorMessage") != null)`, presumably meant to be executed server-side as Java code, isn't within scriptlet tags, so the JavaScript interpreter will try to execute it and fail.  Seems like what you want to be doing is this:

```
<script>
function loginFailure() {<%
           if(request.getParameter("errorMessage") != null) {
               System.out.println("Invalid parameters"); 
               %>
               alert("<%= request.getAttribute("errorMessage") %>");
               <%      
           }%>
</script>
```

That's the simplest fix.  Although you don't really want to be mingling server-side and client-side code to the extent you are either (i.e., putting any Java code within a JavaScript function).  Better to define a `var errorMessage` outside the function, like `var errorMessage="<%=request.getAttribute("errorMessage")==null?"":request.getAttribute("errorMessage").toString()%>"` and then use a JavaScript conditional (not Java, as it seems you were trying to do) which alerts the error message only if its length is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Scriptlet and javascript to display this message:
> ```

```
<%
            String message = (String) request.getAttribute("errorMessage");
            if (message != null) {
            %> 
              <script>
                   alert('<%=message%>');
              </script> 
           <%
            }else{

            %>
            <script>
                 alert("Login Successfull");

            </script>
        <%       
            }
        %>
```